# .htaccess Rewrite code to 301 redirect my URL path to fix canonical issues

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, canonicalization

I discovered recently that a Hostgator tech inserted rewrite code in my `.htaccess` file which 302 redirected all of my pages to `https://example.com` even though I wasn't using that URL path for my sitemap or internal links. Now I have a mix of URL paths indexed by Google and lots of duplicate pages.

Trying to clean it up and use one URL path -> `https://example.com`

This is the code they inserted:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit
```

Can I simply change the `[R,L]` to `[R=301,L]` so that now everything will be a permanent redirect? I will also update all internal links and sitemap to use this URL path.

Comment: "Can I simply change the `[R,L]` to `[R=301,L]`" - if that is all you are asking, then "yes". (Why are you doubting this?) However, these directives do not canonicalise `https://www.example.com` - presumably that is the intention? "`RewriteOptions inherit`" - what directives are you _inheriting_?

Comment: "I discovered recently that a Hostgator tech inserted rewrite code" - was this unprompted? Or were you seeking tech support at the time??

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, my intention is to use this to canonicalise this URL path:  https:// bakpakguide.com and the reason for my question. I wanted to make sure I was accomplishing this. 

I don't think I am inheriting any directives as this is my site's only htaccess file. I don't know why Hostgator added that. 

I was seeking tech support at the time because of SSL issues - not all pages were displaying as https, so they "fixed it" for me but I didn't know at the time that is how they did it.